# Visual studio underlining in red but compiler works perfectly

Tags: cuda, visual-studio-2019

I am currently using Visual studios 2019 with CUDA. However, when I create or open any CUDA file things are underlined in red and marked as "errors" when in reality everything works perfectly fine and the compiler throws no errors. For example: [image]

Is there a way to add CUDA's compiler, nvcc, to visual studios so I won't get these annoying error messages? Or is this completely impossible and something I have to live with? Also, if it helps I am using CMake with the Ninja compiler.

Comment: This is an old and much discussed problem, and there is no real fix

Comment: @talonmies Oh, I do not have any issue with "<< " and  ">>" operators. I can live with those. But my problem is that anything I type that is specific to CUDA is underlined in red. For example, __global__ is underlined in red despite compiling correctly.

Comment: It is the same problem. Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code intellisense only works reliably for plain vanilla C++. It doesn't know anything about CUDA syntax and it can't be modified to parse it without indicating errors.